# Efficient way to handle millions of rows

Tags: sql, performance, import

I have 30 txt files of 2.6 million rows and 150 columns each one. Is transactional bank data. I need to manage it (**78 million rows**) to create variables for each client. I'm working in my personal computer (i7 and 8gb ram).
I imported one file to my local microsoft sql 2000 with **bulk insert**.It took 5 minutes. I created a clustered index and tried to import another one. It was running more than 25 minutes and didn't end. Do I have to delete the index and import it again? Would this way be faster?
Besides, a simple count(id) takes 2 minutes with only the first txt loaded.

How can I handle this data efficiently (I'm also R and Python user)?

Also, most of the fields are numbers but sometimes have symbols like **, so I created the destination table with char fields, which I think is making things slower. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: First, I would suggest using supported software.  The current version of SQL Server is 2014, and SQL Server 2000 has been unsupported for years.

Comment: For bulk insert you should read this: https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ms190421%28v=sql.105%29.aspx